# Incompatible types when assigning an empty tuple to a specialised variable

Tags: python, tuples, mypy, python-typing

I have a variable `path`, which should be a tuple of strings. I want to start with it set to an empty tuple, but mypy complains.

```py
path: Tuple[str] = ()
```

The error is:

> Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[]", variable has type "Tuple[str]")

How can I assign an empty tuple to a typed variable?

#### Motivation

The reason I want to do this is: I want to build up the tuple dynamically, and tuples (unlike lists) can be used as dictionary keys. For example (not what I'm actually doing):

```py
for line in fileob:
    path += (line,)
some_dict[path] = some_object
```

This works well, except that mypy doesn't like the type declaration above. I could use a list and then convert it to a tuple, but it complicates the code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**EDIT:**

You can define a [variable length, homogenous tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple) like this:

```
Tuple[str, ...]
```

You can also create a "a or b" type variable with [`typing.Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union):

```py
from typing import Union

path: Union[Tuple[()], Tuple[str]] = ()
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

By trying to assign an empty tuple to a variable that you have typed to not allow empty tuples, you're effectivly missing the point of typing variables.

I assume that the empty tuple you are trying to assign is just a token value, and that you intend to reassign the variable later in the code (to a tuple that contains only strings.)

In that case, simply let the token value be a tuple that contains a string:

```py
path: Tuple[str] = ('token string')
```

This should stop the error message.

Comment: Also worked for me with more than 1 type, e.g. `tuple[(float | str), ...]` Thanks!