# Incompatible type when using containers

Tags: python-3.x, containers, type-hinting, mypy

I'm stuck with a strange issue with type annotations in Python.  Even though I annotate a default argument (that is a container) or a container variable with the the correct type, `mypy` seems to get confused when the container is empty or when I'm filtering out elements using comprehension.  Here are my examples:

```
from typing import Set, Tuple

_Path_t = Tuple[int]

# default argument example
def my_func(key: str, bases: Tuple[int] = ()):
    pass
```

Running `mypy` on the above results in the following error:

```
error: Incompatible default for argument "bases" \
       (default has type "Tuple[]", argument has type "Tuple[int]")
```

The other error when doing comprehension, can be replicated with the following:

```
seqs: Set[_Path_t] = {tuple(range(n, n + 5)) for n in range(2, 3)}
while seqs:
    seqs = [seq[:-1] for seq in seqs if seq[:-1]]
```

For the assignment line above, `mypy` emits the error:

```
error: Set comprehension has incompatible type Set[Tuple[int, ...]]; \
       expected Set[Tuple[int]]
```

Which is absent in my original code, probably because I am not using range.  The error for the variable reassignment inside the `while`-loop is identical though:

```
error: Set comprehension has incompatible type Set[Tuple[]]; \
       expected Set[Tuple[int]]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I guess the problem stems from the fact that the container can be empty.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566353/incompatible-types-when-assigning-an-empty-tuple-to-a-specialised-variable) answer led me to the solution.  In both cases, I need to annotate with `Tuple[int, ...]`; in essence allowing for an empty container.